# SQL subselect statement very slow on certain machines

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

I've got an sql statement where I get a list of all Ids from a table (Machines).

Then need the latest instance of another row in (Events) where the the id's match so have been doing a subselect.

I need to latest instance of quite a few fields that match the id so have these subselects after one another within this single statement so end up with results similar to this...

This works and the results are spot on, it's just becoming very slow as the Events Table has millions of records. The Machine table would have on average 100 records.

Is there a better solution that subselects? Maybe doing inner joins or a stored procedure?

Help appreciated :)

Comment: FYI, using a `TOP (1)` without an `ORDER BY` is going to return in any arbitrary row (meeting the requirement) being returned, which could easily also result in inconsistent results.

Comment: All subselects seem to be identical. You could use a CTE instead to select the row you want and use it in the outer query. Or a *single* subquery that returns the entire row

Comment: They are identical apart from they're returning the latest of each field. So the latest Count, Value etc... These values obviously aren't on the same row within the Events table (as need the latest of each) so can this be done in a single sub select? Not sure how this would be done with a common table expression? Thanks again.

Comment: Is Events indexed? You probably want a filtered index like `(MachineID, EventCodeID, EventTime) INCLUDE (ID, EventTime, EventCodeID, JobID, [Count], [Value], UserMapID) WHERE Dirty = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply`.  You don't specify how "latest instance" is defined.  Let me assume it is based on the time column:

```
Select a.id, b.*
from TableA a outer apply
     (select top(1) b.Name, b.time, b.weight
      from b
      where b.id = a.id
      order by b.time desc
     ) b;
```

Both `APPLY` and the correlated subquery need an `ORDER BY` to do what you intend.

`APPLY` is a lot like a correlated query in the `FROM` clause -- with two convenient enhances.  A lateral join -- technically what `APPLY` does -- can return multiple rows and multiple columns.